# Can someone explain something in this short Reverse Proxy guide?

Tags: ruby, proxy, reverse-proxy

Forgive my inexperience, but what rake file is he referring to, and how do I run it?

http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/04/reverse-proxy-javascript-app/

Comment: Can you clarify? Post the link to the guide you're referring to?

Comment: Oops, I thought I did, sorry - Edited the question.  Here it is at any rate: http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/04/reverse-proxy-javascript-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like he's set up a Rakefile to start Apache and run it in the foreground.

In your directory, just add that gist to a file named `Rakefile` and then run `rake apache` from the command line.

Alternatively, you could just type what is inside the `exec %Q` block if you don't want to set up a rake file.